# How to use ocLazyLoad dependency injection inside controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, oclazyload

I'm using `ocLazyLoad` to lazy loading my dependencies according to route (and controller), the modules that are already injected to application, but, how can I add a dependency injection inside my controller? Is it possible?

For example, in one of my controllers, I need `chart.js` which also needed to be injected as a dependency to the angular.module but, how is it possible and how should I do it?  I only need the chart inside this controller.

Answer (score 2):

```
            resolve: {
                deps: ['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {
                    return $ocLazyLoad.load([
                        'chart.js'/* path of your chart js file*/
                    ],{ serie: true });
                }]
            }
```

Put this code in your state (In routing).

Comment: You should describe better than this! Actually, it is not clear where you mean, the piece of code you shared can be placed anywhere... So, I think you need to clarify

Comment: You need to put this code in config.

`$stateProvider.state("test", {
                    url: "test",
                    templateUrl: 'test',
                    controller:  'testController',
                  resolve: {
                deps: ['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {
                    return $ocLazyLoad.load([
                        'chart.js'/* path of your chart js file*/
                    ],{ serie: true });
                }]
            }
});`
I think now it is clear. Let me know if you still need more clarification.

Comment: But I have the same problem, I do not use the route library ($stateProvider). Actually i am not familier with that. Thanks

Comment: What is your exact situation? Can you share with me